# which executes first when we compare Price Rules and Product rules(order of execution in CPQ)

Tags: cpq

What is the order of execution in cpq. when we have price rules and product rules ,which one executes first when we create quote lines

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, price rules runs first than product rules.
Price rules are kind of like logic in before update/inert trigger and product rules like validation rules on objects.